Finding nunique of a column grouped by another column
I'm trying to reverse engineer what the following functions are doing in a codebase I am working with at work:
def _helper(df):
  return (df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])
          .size()
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns={0: 'count'}))

def nunique_counts(df, col):
  df   = _helper(df)
  data = df[['a', col]].groupby('a').nunique()[col]
  return data

I had always thought that nunique_counts returns the count of number of unique col values for each unique value of column a, but I'm not sure that this is actually the case because we can just simply do this, i think:
def nunique_counts(df, col):
  return df.groupby('a')[col].nunique()

What is the original function attempting to do? Also the count column that was created in _helper doesn't seem to be used, and further, the groupby dependence on column c shouldn't affect the final results so I'm not sure why it's even done -- though I'm not 100% confident of this.
Also empirically on the problems I'm working with, the 2 do not seem to yield the same results. Specifically, the second one produces counts that are >= the former one
To address @Quang's comment
In [2]: def _helper(df): 
   ...:   return (df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c']) 
   ...:           .size() 
   ...:           .reset_index() 
   ...:           .rename(columns={0: 'count'})) 
   ...:                                                                             

In [3]: import pandas as pd                                                         

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1, 2, 3], "b": [0,0,1,1], "c":[0,0,0,0]})       

In [5]: _helper(df)                                                                 
Out[5]: 
   a  b  c  count
0  0  0  0      1
1  1  0  0      1
2  2  1  0      1
3  3  1  0      1

In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 0, 1, 1], "b": [0,0,1,1], "c":[0,0,0,0]})       

In [7]: _helper(df)                                                                 
Out[7]: 
   a  b  c  count
0  0  0  0      2
1  1  1  0      2

It turns out nan values in column c was the culprit. Consider the following:
In [23]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 0, 2, 3], "b": [0,0,1,1], "c": [np.nan,np.nan,0
    ...: ,0]})                                                                      

In [24]: df                                                                         
Out[24]: 
   a  b    c
0  0  0  NaN
1  0  0  NaN
2  2  1  0.0
3  3  1  0.0

In [25]: nunique_counts(df, "b")                                                    
Out[25]: 
a
2    1
3    1
Name: b, dtype: int64

In [26]: nunique_counts1(df, "b")    # I defined nunique_counts1 to be the modified implementation                                                
Out[26]: 
a
0    1
2    1
3    1
Name: b, dtype: int64


Yes, they count two different things. The implemented code first counts the sizes of the unique triplet a,b,c, giving just one single column count; now nunique_counts(df, col) only works with col=='count', any other value would throw an error.

@QuangHoang "The implemented code first counts the sizes of the unique triplet a,b,c, giving just one single column count" hmm, this is not what I'm seeing, i still see the original columns along with the count column in the output of _helper. I'll edit an example into the OP

oh, sorry, I missed the .reset_index part in the helper. That said, col=b or col=c would give the same answer as your function. It's just col=count is not present in your function.

@QuangHoang Yes, I feel like my proposal should produce the same answer, and it does on the problems I tested with, but in the original problem I'm working on, it produces different answers (that problem is too large for me to manually check what the correct output should be)

Logically, they should be the same, unless there are nan values. I'm not sure how nan can play a factor in nunique, but it might be worth looking into.

@QuangHoang ah good point in checking for nan. I just checked in the actual problem I'm working with and all the nan columns are in c. None of the other columns have nan values. I think the groupby on c with nan values may be the culprit

Can you give more hints on the original names for a/b/c? This context might help guessing the role of each function.

@mozway yes, 'a' is a datetime column, b is some identifier (you can think of it as a hash value), and c is the origin of the row -- i think the dataframe is concatenated across various sets of data, and the origin is an identifier that points to the data source

Is nunique_counts(df, "count")used anywhere in the code?

The _helper function aggregates on unique combinations of a/b/c and adds a new column with the count of rows per group (removing any other column in the process) and also removing the rows with NaNs in a/b/c since the dropna parameter of groupby is by default True.
For instance:
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0,2,2,2,1], "b": [0,0,1,1,2], "c":[0,0,0,0,None]})

   a  b    c
0  0  0  0.0
1  2  0  0.0
2  2  1  0.0  # duplicated
3  2  1  0.0  #
4  1  2  NaN      # this will be dropped

_helper(df)

   a  b    c  count
0  0  0  0.0      1
1  2  0  0.0      1
2  2  1  0.0      2  # 2 duplicated rows

Thus, _helper acts more or less like a dropna, and as proposed you should be able to replace the original function by a single function, using:
df.dropna(subset=['a', 'b', 'c']).groupby('a')[col].nunique()

Unless the value passed to col is col='count', which of course is the column created by _helper. In this case you need the original function.
